# How to create nested child objects in JavaScript from array?

Tags: javascript

This is the given array:

```
[{
  key: 1,
  nodes: {}
}, {
  key: 2,
  nodes: {}
}, {
  key: 3,
  nodes: {}
}]
```

How to create nested child objects in JavaScript from this array?

```
[{
  key: 1,
  nodes: [{
    key: 2,
    nodes: [{
      key: 3,
      nodes: []
    }]
  }]
}];
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a pretty good use case for [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) which allows you to build the structure from the inside out:

```js
let arr = [{
  key: 1,
  nodes: {}
}, {
  key: 2,
  nodes: {}
}, {
  key: 3,
  nodes: {}
}]

let a = arr.reduceRight((arr, {key}) => [{key, nodes: arr}],[])

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine. Try this below code

```
  const firstArray = [{ key: 1, nodes: {} }, { key: 2, nodes: {} }, { key: 3, nodes: {} }];
firstArray.reverse();
const nestedObject = firstArray.reduce((prev, current) => {
    return {
        ...current,
            nodes:[{...prev}]
    }
}, {});

console.log(nestedObject)
```